# Submit button doesn't call controller function - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to create a form to store some data. However, when I click on the submit button, nothing happens other than refreshing the page. The request gets fired (shows up in DevTools -> Network). The routes should be fine, since it worked an hour ago, and now it doesn't. I removed every single input from the form just to see if that could call the store function from the controller. However, no luck.

The form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{route('bookings.store')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            @csrf

<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

The controller (should just print the string on the page, but doesnt):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'nume' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required'
        ]);

        return "wtf";
```

The route list:

```
| Domain | Method    | URI                     | Name             | Action                                                                 | Middleware   |
+--------+-----------+-------------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+
|        | GET|HEAD  | /                       |                  | Closure                                                                | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | about                   | about            | App\Http\Controllers\PageController@about                              | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | api/user                |                  | Closure                                                                | api,auth:api |
|        | POST      | bookings                | bookings.store   | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@store                           | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | bookings                | bookings.index   | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@index                           | web          |
|        | GET|HEAD  | bookings/create         | bookings.create  | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@create                          | web,auth     |
|        | PUT|PATCH | bookings/{booking}      | bookings.update  | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@update                          | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | bookings/{booking}      | bookings.show    | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@show                            | web          |
|        | DELETE    | bookings/{booking}      | bookings.destroy | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@destroy                         | web,auth     |
|        | GET|HEAD  | bookings/{booking}/edit | bookings.edit    | App\Http\Controllers\BookingController@edit                            | web,auth     |
```

Comment: Could you post the network requests? Maybe a picture of the or the list from the console?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, here is a screenshot: https://imgur.com/a/pac2jpo

Comment: Maybe validating throwing an excepting but you are not catcing and you get blank page. When you are trying to submit form works, put dd($request->all()); or smt. to top of your controller. Otherwise nobody can not now anything from a blank page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the provided code, the error I see is that the `$this->validate()` function call in the controller is failing, and so, it must be throwing a [ValidationException](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.html).

When a validation exception is thrown, and no `try{} catch{}` is in use, the default behaviour is dictated by Laravel's [Handler](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/6.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php) class:

- Line 203-205: If the exception thrown is a ValidationException.
- Line 254-263: Call `invalid()` for HTML or `invalidJson()` for JSON response.
- Line 272-277 (if called invalid()): redirect back with flashed errors in session.
- Line 286-292 (if called invalidJson()): return JSON object with errors.

After understanding how the ValidationException works, now looking at your code, we know the validation is failing, and so, you are being "redirected back" (what looks like a refresh) and no errors are being printed, because they are flashed in the session.

What can you do?

To see the errors, you can print them, it is explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors). To pass the validation, just add the form inputs again :)

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you! I changed some inputs in the form and forgot to modify the validation. I thought the problem was in the HTML part since I didn't see the controller get called.